# pip install error on Mac OS X and Mamp Pro

Tags: django, pip

I'm having trouble installing pip as it can't find my mysql_config file. I'm on a Mac I'm using Mamp Pro the config file is located here in Mamp: /Users/james/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my_cnf

I've changed the site.cfg file to point to this:

```
mysql_config = /Users/james/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my_cnf
```

Which didn't work. I've placed the mysql_config on my path via:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/james/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my_cnf
export PATH
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/james/.pip/pip.log
(thecarbonlist)JamesApps:thecarbonlist james$ sudo pip install django mysql-python
Downloading/unpacking django
Running setup.py egg_info for package django
Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
Running setup.py egg_info for package mysql-python
sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Users/james/Projects/current/code/project/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
sh: mysql_config: command not found

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

File "/Users/james/Projects/current/code/project/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 15, in <module>

metadata, options = get_config()

File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config

libs = mysql_config("libs_r")

File "setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config

raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

What am I doing wrong? I would like to carry on using Mamp Pro, does anyone know how to fix this as I'm out of ideas!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running install command with sudo you are using the elevated accounts path, that may not include mysql_config.

Try this:

```
james$ which mysql_config
james$ sudo which mysql_config
```

and make sure both return the same path to mysql_config.

Comment: They are now both: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config I managed to fix it reinstalled mysql binary and mysql-python and set the path     
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
    export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/